# multiply the condition of a group contained in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I would need to multiply the condition of a group contained in a regular expression, at the moment I can only understand an exact equality, example:

```
stringA = 'a-a';
stringB = 'a-z';
var r = (/([a-z])(\-\1)/g).test(str);
(r).test(stringA);//true
(r).test(stringB);//false, but i want true
```

I just want to automatically understand that there is an [a-z] condition and not a condition [a], such as the present one. Can you help me?

Edit:

```
stringC = 'The apples are 44-The apples are 44';
stringD = 'The apples are 44-The apples are 45';
var Nr = (The apples are [0-9]{2})(\-\1);
(Nr).test(stringC);//true
(Nr).test(stringD);//false, but i want true
```

Added 1 more example.

Comment: Could you give more examples? matching and not? Thanks

Comment: Of course try to see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current regex, you used `\1` after placing one single character inside a group which made it repeat matching that single character. The solution for this is to place `\1` after a group that contains this condition `a-z` in order for `\1` to repeat matching the whole condition.

Try this regex:

```
([a-z]\-[a-z])(\1?)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GCgk5h/1/

Comment: I can not repeat the same string as you did ([a-z] \ - [a-z]), because the real regexp is too long and slows down the computer that uses it, for that I look for a way to repeat the instruction without rewrite it.

Comment: @Helpme This function `\1` cannot be used to repeat matching different numbers. How about something like this? https://regex101.com/r/GCgk5h/2/

Comment: @Helpme This is not possible my friend, this function is designed to repeat exactly the same characters, NOT the same category (i.e. letters, numbers etc.). You could though place your regex inside a group, and repeat that group several times without using `\1`. Check it out here: https://regex101.com/r/GCgk5h/4/

Comment: @Helpme My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object can be build dynamically :

```js
var re = new RegExp( "(1)(-1)".replace(/1/g, "[a-z]") )

console.log( re )
console.log( re.test('a-z') )
```